Is it possible to assign distinct colors to the key and value texts within the same node when utilizing Antv g6 tree node?
For the past few weeks, I've been utilizing the Antv g6 custom tree node to represent the json hierarchy. Our project requires some specific customizations, particularly, we aim to display the key and value text in distinct colors to clearly differentiate between the attributes. I'm curious if there's a way to customize this aspect, similar to how text formatting is done in the tooltip option. This would greatly enhance our ability to convey information more effectively.
Note: Key and value means "name": "Modeling Methods**(Key): object(value)**"
Below is the sample payload:
{
"name": "Modeling Methods: object",
"children": [
{
"name": "Classification: array",
"children": [
{ "name": "Logistic regression: string" },
{ "name": "Linear discriminant analysis: string" },
{ "name": "Rules: string" },
{ "name": "Decision trees: integer" },
{ "name": "Naive Bayes: date" },
{ "name": "K nearest neighbor: float" },
{ "name": "Probabilistic neural network: string" },
{ "name": "Support vector machine: string" }
]
}
]
}
I've reviewed the antv g6 documentation and various forums, and while there's a lot of discussion about setting the color for the entire node, I haven't found information on how to adjust the colors for specific keys and values.
